# Proof of Johnsen Lindenstrauss by concentration of measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, random-matrices

Question: In Theorem 3 before "..By choosing $t=\sqrt{\frac{k}{5n}}$ we get $m\ge\Omega(\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}})$.." What is this process exactly? Why is an exponential bound critical here? Why wouldn't other type of bounds such as $\frac{1}{n}$ work?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be better if you can attach a link to your pdf file or provide a source of your pdf file. Otherwise, your image is quite blurry.